# Arrays asList() accepts instance of class

Tags: java

How Array.asList() accepts instance of class?
 I understand, it can accept

```
    // creating Arrays of String type 
    String a[] = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" }; 

    // getting the list view of Array 
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a);
```

But Why its accepting below, its supposed to accept only array?

```
Arrays.asList(new Readexcel());
```

Comment: `asList` is a varargs method. `Arrays.asList(new Readexcel())` is syntactic sugar meaning `Arrays.asList(new Object[]{new Readexcel()})`

Comment: @AndyTurner Or is it `Arrays.asList(new Readexcel[] { new Readexcel() })`?

Comment: @MCEmperor I actually had to look this up and try it, because I realized I didn't really know. Yes, it is that. It faintly surprises me that it's determined at the call site, rather than the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the method `Arrays.asList(T ...a)`.

`T ...a` -> this syntax says that you can pass any number of arguments, but they will be of the same type `<T>` . So you can pass any number of arguments of any type not restricted to array and it will return the list of those type of arguments. 
Eg : `Arrays.asList(1)` or `Arrays.asList(1,2)` will return `List<Integer>`

This concept was introduced in JDK5

Comment: I think because the OP is asking about passing an instance of a class. Instead you are describing what is the behaviour if we pass more than one arguments.

Comment: But I guess , at last he asked why its accepting that object , it was supposed to accept only array, that's why I described the behavior that it can accept any type because of <T>

Comment: Sorry, but maybe there is a misunderstanding beetween you and the OP. He is cleary asking "But Why its accepting below, its supposed to accept only array? Arrays.asList(new Readexcel());" Maybe, next time, you could ask more info to the op with a comment.

Comment: @Dwhitz The value 1 is an instance of 'any number of arguments'.

Comment: @user207421 Yes of course, but he missed the explanation that Andy Turner did in his comments that is the right answer for the op.